# SQL: Delete differences from table where multiple conditions must be met

Tags: c#, sql

Example-Table. Following table has no primary key (only foreign):

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
1       1         A       X
1       1         A       Y
1       1         B       Y
1       1         A       -
1       1         -       -
1       2         A       X
1       2         A       Y
1       2         B       -
1       2         A       -
1       2         -       -
```

Now there comes a List with exact same values - but one or more of them are missing.
For example the row with 1-1-A-Y and the one with 1-1-B-Y

I do not want to say "delete from .. where col1=1 and col2=1 and col3=A and col4=Y" and so on.
If it was that easy, I would not ask here.

It has to work over a difference-evaluation.

I tried it with User Defined Table Types (representing arrays), where I hold all values which should remain, and then simply call `delete from .. where [value] not in (select s from @my_array)`

It works for ONE column, but as soon as there is a second, it (obviously) fails.
Why? Because in above example, in the first and second column there is the SAME value, and as soon as it is equal, the statement "not in" is false.

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to accomplish this?

Comment: What about `delete from table s where not exists(select * from @my_array a where s.col1 = a.col1 AND s.col2 = a.col2 AND s.col3 = a.col3 AND s.col4 = a.col4`?

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, but the problem is, that this way all other rows would be deleted as well, if they are not in the array.

Comment: I thought that you wanted to delete all the rows that are not in the array.  So you want to delete some of the rows that are not in the array, which ones do you not delete?

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server for the database, maybe you could use the MERGE statement.

It allows you to do some actions according to the match or not match between the rows of two differents sources (tables, select statement,...)

[Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx) is the official article from Microsoft.

Hope it can help!

Answer (score 0):

I am little confused by your description and example, but as i can see you want to delete rows if they have empty cell?

Here is function for that:

```
public static void RemoveNullColumnFromDataTable(DataTable dt, string[] columnName)
{
    for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        foreach (string column in columnName)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[i][column] == DBNull.Value)
            {
                dt.Rows[i].Delete();
            }
        }
    }
    dt.AcceptChanges();
}
```

so you run it like:

```
string[] columnsToFilter = {"Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4");
staticClass.RemoveNullColumnFromDataTable(yourDataTable, columnsToFilter);
```

Comment: Not if they have an empty cell, the row is completely gone